# "java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date" thrown for time text

Tags: java, date, datetime, calendar

Hi I am Calling below function to find time elapsed, till that date, It is working fine for all but following input : `12:46:21 PM`

```
public Long timeDifference(String weboutput) {
    try {
        Calendar calendar = GregorianCalendar.getInstance();
        Calendar today = new GregorianCalendar();
        Date inputTime;
        if (weboutput.length() <= 10) { // for data fetched for current date.
            DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss a", Locale.US);
            inputTime = formatter.parse(weboutput);
            calendar.setTime(inputTime);
            int hour = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR);
            int minute = calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
            int second = calendar.get(Calendar.SECOND);
            today.setTime(new Date());
            today.set(Calendar.HOUR, hour);
            today.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
            today.set(Calendar.SECOND, second);
        } else {
            if (weboutput.length() <= 15) { // for data for earlier date in same year or month.
                DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd hh:mm a", Locale.US);
                inputTime = formatter.parse(weboutput);
                calendar.setTime(inputTime);
                int hour = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR);
                int minute = calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
                int month = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
                int date = calendar.get(Calendar.DATE);
                today.setTime(new Date());
                today.set(Calendar.HOUR, hour);
                today.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
                today.set(Calendar.MONTH, month);
                today.set(Calendar.DATE, date);
            } else { // for data with different year.
                DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd, yyyy hh:mm:ss a", Locale.US);
                inputTime = formatter.parse(weboutput);
                calendar.setTime(inputTime);
                int hour = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR);
                int minute = calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
                int second = calendar.get(Calendar.SECOND);
                int month = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
                int date = calendar.get(Calendar.DATE);
                int year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
                today.setTime(new Date());
                today.set(Calendar.HOUR, hour);
                today.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
                today.set(Calendar.SECOND, second);
                today.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
                today.set(Calendar.MONTH, month);
                today.set(Calendar.DATE, date);
            }
        }
        Date retrivedDate = today.getTime();
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        Date currentDate = cal.getTime();
        difference = currentDate.getTime() - retrivedDate.getTime();
        System.out.println(retrivedDate);
        System.out.println(currentDate);
        System.out.println(difference);

    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return difference;
}

public boolean alarmValue(Long alarmTime) {
    if (alarmTime <= 1800000) // change this value for Alarm duration, currently 30 min = 30* 60 s = 1800 * 1000 ms = 1800000 ms.
        return false;
    else
        return true;
}
```

the error is as follows:

```
    java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "12:46:21 PM"
    at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:357)
    at rcm.Selenium.Test.Calculations.timeDifference(Calculations.java:29)
    at rcm.Selenium.Test.RcmSeleniumTest.main(RcmSeleniumTest.java:89)
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at rcm.Selenium.Test.Calculations.alarmValue(Calculations.java:76)
    at rcm.Selenium.Test.RcmSeleniumTest.main(RcmSeleniumTest.java:90)
```

Kindly help me with this.

Comment: Why do you expect `12:46:21 PM` to be parsed by `MMM dd hh:mm a` format?

Comment: There are 11 characters in `12:46:21 PM` - the space counts. This means you are using `MMM dd hh:mm a` to parse it which is an invalid format.

Comment: MMM dd hh:mm a is for other date formats, kindly go through the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`"12:46:21 PM"` has 11 digits and therefore doesn't pass your first test (which is for `<= 10` digits) for the format `"hh:mm:ss a"`.

Comment: Hi Thanks for highlighting, was missed that one.

Comment: @PranavNath now you have this working I recommend posting it on [codereview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for feedback.